# How can I view a log of system use?

Tags: server, log, syslog

Is there a log or software application for interpreting, e.g. `/var/log/syslog*` so that I can get statistics on system use?

I am interested in the frequency of use of a machine by different users; some statistics about the programs or resources used would also be helpful.

Comment: what kind of information do you intend to gain by interpreting?  Just read it like it is, and if you do not know what something means, google it.

Comment: It depends on what information you are looking for, there are several open source tools to choose from. I personally like  logwatch http://www.linux-mag.com/id/7800/

Comment: @Matt, a summary of, e.g. how many times user x has logged in, how long they were logged in, and what programs they executed.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely you would need to configure your Syslog daemon to capture what your looking for and then use a log parsing tool such as logwatch or Sawmill. I included a couple of links that may help. I would recommend installing Syslog-NG and then using the front-end tools in the 'debianadmin' link below.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxLogFiles

http://www.debianadmin.com/syslog-ng-web-interface-front-end-or-gui-tools.html